# How to fetch record from mysql using last inserted id?

Tags: php, mysql

This is what i tried and it works fine..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM patient where id = (SELECT max(id) FROM patient)";   
result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $patientid=$row["id"];
        $patientname=$row["name"];
        $patientrefer=$row["referto"];
        $patientdisease=$row["disease"];
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
```

but whenever i replaced the query with

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM patient where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()";
```

It always return `0` results.

Comment: last_insert_id will work only after a insert query.Whenever you insert a record into a table ,then only you can get last_insert_id .

Comment: use mysql_insert_id() instead

Comment: use `mysql_insert_id()`

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: for last insert id to work, be it in pure SQL or in PHP, you need to run an insert query first. Then only you will get that to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get last (latest) record from your table, you can do descending `ORDER BY` together with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM patient ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

You don't need `LAST_INSERT_ID` in that case at all. Moreover with concurrent inserts you cannot ensure that user's last insert is really the latest one by using `LAST_INSERT_ID`.